# How to loop through array backwards from certain index point

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am trying to loop through an array backwards starting from an index number of `96`.

```
for (let i = keyToValue2.length[96] - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    console.log(keyToValue2[i])
}
```

This is my code so far and I can't find any posts about this.
Also, this is my first post sorry if I didn't type code correctly.

Comment: Please mention what problem you are facing.

Comment: You just initialized i with a wrong value. You should use `let i = 96 - 1` instead of `let i = keyToValue2.length[96] - 1` .

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to slice the array (which uses additional memory, as it creates a new array) to do that.

What you are describing is a loop that starts at `index = 96` until it reaches `0`, decreasing `index` one by one.

So you just need to change `let i = keyToValue2.length[96] - 1` to `let i = 96`.

Here's an example using an array with `32` values and logging them backwards, starting at index `16`. Just used these values because StackOverflow snippets limit the number of log entries:

```js
// This creates a new array with 32 numbers (0 to 31, both included):
const array = new Array(32).fill(null).map((_, i) => `Element at index ${ i }.`);

// We start iterating at index 16 and go backwards until 0 (both included):
for (let i = 16; i >= 0; --i) {
  console.log(array[i])
}
```

If you want to make sure the index `96` actually exists in your array, then use `let i = Math.min(96, keyToValue2.length - 1`:

```js
// This creates a new array with 32 numbers (0 to 31, both included):
const array = new Array(32).fill(null).map((_, i) => `Element at index ${ i }.`);

// We start iterating at index 31 (as this array doesn't have 64 elements, it has only 32)
// and go backwards until 0 (both included):
for (let i = Math.min(64, array.length - 1); i >= 0; --i) {
  console.log(array[i])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

slice array up to which index you want, then loop it reverse order.

```
var sliced = keyToValue2.slice(0, 96);

for (let i = sliced.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    console.log(keyToValue2[i])
}
```